# Redireccionamiento a dashboard segun usuario en laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Quiero redirigir a un usuario según su rol en Laravel(estoy usando la versión 9), tengo tres roles: Administrador, Cliente y Asistente. Ya he definido las rutas y controller que se encargaran de gestionarlo; pero en el archivo de jetstrem **RouteServiceProvider** en su constante HOME me he percatado que aunque yo redireccione a la vista correspondiente, igual me lleva a la ruta dashboard. Como podria evitar que no me envie al dashboard y solo me redireccione a las rutas de acuerdo al rol del usuario. Dejo capturas de codigo.

Mi controller donde redirecciono segun el rol:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class WebController extends Controller
{

    public function acceso(){
        
        return view('auth.login');
        
    }

    public function logearse(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password), true)) {
            if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Administrador'))
                return redirect('/dashboard');     

            if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Asistente'))
                return redirect('/dashboard');    
            
            if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Cliente'))
                
                return redirect('/dashboard-cliente');
        }
        else{
            return view('auth.login');
        }
    }    

}
```

El codigo del RouteServiceProvider:

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * Typically, users are redirected here after authentication.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = 'dashboard';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, and other route configuration.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::middleware('api')
                ->prefix('api')
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));           

            Route::middleware('web','auth')                
                ->group(base_path('routes/customer.php'));
        });
    }
    
}
```

Mis rutas en web.php(rutas del admin) y customer.php (rutas del cliente):
}

//rutas de login y dashboard

```
Route::controller(WebController::class)->group(function (){
    Route::get('/','acceso');
    Route::post('/logearse','logearse'); 
});

Route::controller(HomeController::class)->group(function (){
    Route::get('/dashboard','index')->middleware('can:Ver Dashboard')->name('dashboard');
});
```

//Rutas clientes

```
Route::controller(CustomerController::class)->group(function (){
    Route::get('/dashboard-cliente', 'index')->middleware('can:Ver Menú Clientes')->name('dashboard-customer');
    Route::get('/lista_consulta_clientes', 'listarOrderCustomers');
    Route::get('/order/{order}','show');
});
```

Espero puedan ayudarme como poder dar solucion a la redireccion, porque cuando me logeo como cliente envia al **DASHBOARD** y deberia mandarme a la ruta **dashboard-cliente**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que veo, tu planteamiento del problema está un poco confuso, pero entiendo que el problema que tienes viene dado a que estás utilizando el middleware `auth` esto implica que estarás utilizando toda la lógica que viene ya establecida por JetStream en conjunto a Fortify.

Por ende, para cambiar el comportamiento de este middleware deberás dirigirte aa provider de Fortify: `App\Providers\FortifyServiceProvider` y en el metodo resgiter hacer hacer uso del `LoginResponse`:

Aquí hice un ejemplo orientado a tu caso, lo primero que hice fue recuperar el usuario que está haciendo el login, luego validar que la variable `$user` no este vacía en conjunto a la comprobación de la clave del usuario y la clave que es enviada por el request, además, de tener el role que deseas, lo único que debes hacer son las otras dos validaciones.

```
#Agregar
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginResponse;

public function register()
{
    $this->app->instance(LoginResponse::class, new class implements LoginResponse {
        public function toResponse($request)
        {
            $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

            if ($user &&
                Hash::check($request->password, $user->password) &&
                $user->hasRole('Administrador')) {
                # code...
                return redirect('/dashboard');
            }

            return redirect('/');
        }
    });
}
```

Para más información puedes visitar la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/fortify#customizing-authentication-redirects) de laravel.

Comment: mechavarria, muchas gracias me funciono para el tema de la redireccion en base al rol, tengo una consulta para que sirve el LoginResponse y  Hash::check, no los habia escuchado, zorry estoy aprendiendo laravel aun.

Comment: Si, `LoginResponse` lo que permite es inyectar una nueva instancia personalizada dentro de una clase o interfaz en un contenedor de servicios para Laravel. Esto significa que cuando haces uso de `LoginResponse` se utilizará la implementación personalizada en vez de la predeterminada que trae Fortity. En pocas palabras, te permite cambiar la lógica o comportamiento de un método inyectando el tuyo.

Comment: Hash::check es un método que trae Laravel el cual permite compara una contraseña obtenida como parámetro por ejemplo `($request->password)` y compararla con una ya previamente guardada en la base de datos. Esta última encriptada.

Comment: Documentación para la personalización de redirecciones:
[redirrección](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/fortify#customizing-authentication-redirects)

Documentación de los services container:
[servicesContainer](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/container)

Documentación de los hashing de Laravel:
[hashing](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/hashing#verifying-that-a-password-matches-a-hash)

Comment: Puedes ver también:
[cuando usarlos](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/container#when-to-use-the-container)

Comment: @JonathanSandoval se requiere más información para poder ayudarte

Comment: Hola mechavarria, podrias ayudarme con esta pregunta porfas. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/603874/problema-con-validacion-de-imagen-en-laravel

Comment: Se que no es mi publicación, pero creo que si respondio esta pregunta correctamente puede ayudarme, necesito mandar una variable a la vista auth.register de jetstream v4, pero por mas que busco no sé donde tengo que escribir el codigo para que me lo mande, por ejemplo si quisiera enviar el listado de roles a la ruta de registro, como y donde lo hago @mechavarria? gracias.

Comment: Saludos,

Edita o crea una pregunta explicando bien tu caso y así te ayudo de una mejor manera.

@MauEspaña

Comment: @MauEspaña respondí tu pregunta, si puedes corrígela  para que cumpla con las normas de la comunidad y así pueda servirle a otros desarrolladores.