# Donde se encuentra el RegisterController de Jetstream V4 en laravel 10?

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

Necesito enviar una variable que muestre en listado, como por ejemplo companies a la vista de registro de usuario, pero no encuentro donde poder hacerlo, alguien sabe donde puedo encontrar dicho controlador o como envío una variable a la vista auth.register?

Gracias.

Comment: as intentando un `php artisan route:list --name=register`

Comment: Podes buscar un archivo con cualquier IDE decente... bah, cualquier sistema operativo tiene un buscador de archivos. Por lo demás falta información

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ más que buscar un archivo es saber cómo y dónde hacer lo que él quiere. Nada que ver con IDEs

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es personalizar el método que controla la ruta del register. Algo parecido a lo que viste en mi [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/603219/281567) en la cual comentaste.

Básicamente lo que debes hacer es dirigirte a `App\Providers\FortifyServiceProvider` y colocar el método `registerView` y hacerle la personalización a este.

Ejemplo:
(En mi caso, en el proyecto que hice la prueba estaba usando inertia, pero te dejo un ejemplo con blade).

Inertia:

```
Fortify::registerView(function () {
    $companies = Company::all();
    return Inertia::render('Auth/Register', compact('companies'));
});
```

Blade:

```
Fortify::registerView(function () {
    $companies = Company::all();
    return view('auth.register', compact('companies'));
});
```

Todo esto se explica de una mejor manera en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/fortify#registration) de Laravel, dale un view.

Espero que te sirva!